# java.lang.IllegalStateException: not started exception occurs at line <sonar:sonar/>

Tags: java, ant, sonarqube

I am trying to configure sonar for my project. First I am trying in local environment. Below is my configuration

```
<project name="dev" default="war" xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant">

<!-- Define the SonarQube global properties (the most usual way is to pass these properties via the command line) -->
  <property name="sonar.host.url" value="http://localhost:9000/sonar" />

<!-- Define the SonarQube project properties -->
  <property name="sonar.projectKey" value="org.codehaus.sonar:sonarqube-scanner-ant" />
  <property name="sonar.projectName" value="Example of SonarQube Scanner for Ant Usage" />
  <property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="1.0" />
  <property name="sonar.language" value="java" />
  <property name="sonar.sources" value="src" />
  <property name="sonar.java.binaries" value="build" />
  <property name="sonar.java.libraries" value="lib/*.jar" />
  <property name="sonar.sourceEncoding" value="UTF-8" />

<!-- Code for clean compile the java files code comes here -->

<!-- Define SonarQube Scanner for Ant Target -->
  <target name="sonar"> 
    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
      <!-- Update the following line, or put the "sonarqube-ant-task-*.jar" file in your "$HOME/.ant/lib" folder -->
      <classpath path="C:/eclipse-oxygen2-wf/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.10.1.v20170504-0840/lib/sonarqube-ant-task-2.5.jar" />
    </taskdef>

    <sonar:sonar/>

  </target>

</project>
```

I am using sonarqube7.2.1 ansonarqube-ant-task-2.5.jar. When I run the below command it gives me IllegalStateException

```
ant sonar
```

Is there something I am missing here?

Below is the console output

```
Buildfile: C:\workspace\project_sonar\build.xml
sonar:
[sonar:sonar] Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.1 compiled on February 2 2017
[sonar:sonar] SonarQube Ant Task version: 2.5
[sonar:sonar] Loaded from: file:/C:/sonar/sonarqube-ant-task-2.5.jar
[sonar:sonar] User cache: C:\Users\Usha\.sonar\cache

BUILD FAILED
C:\workspace\project_sonar\build.xml:231: java.lang.IllegalStateException: not started
```

Comment: Could you provide the full exception?

Comment: This is the exception thrown 
     'java.lang.IllegalStateException: not started'

Comment: Could you check that a real sonarqube server exists for the url `http://localhost:9000/sonar` ?
Note: Usually, the local instance url is: http://localhost:9000

Comment: The localhost server is up and launched. Is there something to do with Security (Authorization)?

Comment: Yes, you should have the properties set for username and password. https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters#AnalysisParameters-Authentication

Comment: I added sonar.login and sonar.password in the properties. Still I get the same error.

Comment: I have added the console output in the main question section.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem ever? I am facing similar error on a project which was always working and suddenly stopped working. I dont see any changes that have been done recently which would cause this to stop working.